# How to make JScrollPane JScrollBar act like osx scrollbars that only show on mouse over

Tags: swing, hide, jscrollpane, jscrollbar

I want to minimize the real-estate that scroll bars are taking up in my swing application. Is there any way to have them perform like osx scroll bars that only show on mouse over? Otherwise is there a way to just not show them but still be able to scroll?

thanks

Comment: For what it's worth: on OS X 10.7.4 the scroll bars are always shown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the *getVerticalScrollBar().setVisible(false)* and *SetWheelScrollingEnabled(boolean handleWheel)* methods. But if you want you display them when they are in use than that's a bit tricky. you will have to add a mouseListener for the mouseWheel and create a 2D graphics component. if u just show and hide a normal *JScrollBar* (using the setVisible(boolean visible) method) the viewing area will also change and it'll look very abrupt. U will need to create an overlay using the *paint()/repaint()* methods.

Comment: this is very useful, thanks. Do you think I should override the paint method on a JScrollBar class or just make a generic JComponent that I override the pain method on? Lastly, to have text be visible in the custom scroll area will I need to do some constrain to parent layout where I overlay a non opaque component?

Comment: I haven't tried so you have to find it on your own. But, if you have JComponents I'm sure they will use up your precious "real estate". you will need to add grapihics 2D objects and move them in your mouseWheel listener. Make sure that that you overlay them OVER the swing components cos otherwise they will be drawn underneath and wont b visible

Comment: And im sorry i didn't understand the second question in your comment. If its a vital one, I'd suggest you posting another question